# h2o random forest deploy it in SQL

Tags: sql, r, oracle11g, h2o

I would like to use h2o model (either run in R or in flow) as an operational predictions. However, I would like to run it directly from Oracle sql. Is there currently a way that h2o translate .predict in sql code?
Thanks

Comment: If your DB can support Java, check this out: https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-release/h2o/rel-markov/1/docs-website/userguide/scorePOJO.html

Comment: Thanks I will try that.

Answer (score 2):

This is hopefully a nudge in the right direction, but definitely not a complete answer.

Looking at this documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/create_function.htm#LNPLS01370

It looks like the CREATE FUNCTION capability allows the creation of Java functions.

You could perhaps take an H2O-generated POJO (Plain Old Java Object), wrap it in a Java function, and call it as part of a select statement.

Here is a pointer to a tutorial for how to do this for Hive:

http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o-tutorials/latest-stable/tutorials/hive_udf_template/index.html

Answer (score -1):

That's not possible from within Oracle SQL - Oracle SQL databases can't execute R code natively. What you could do, is generate your predictions in R and then write them to a table in the Oracle SQL DB.

Comment: This path exactly was what I was trying to avoid. It costs time to dwld data from oracle to R.

Comment: Tom said above that you would run Java, not R code. https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-docs/src/product/howto/POJO_QuickStart.md